# Implementing IEquatable<T> in a mutable type

Tags: c#, .net, equals, iequatable

I have a class that represents an external physical measuring device. The simplified version looks like this:

```
public class Device {
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }
}
```

`Tag` is a user-defined value for identifying the device. `Address` is the value used by an adapter to communicate with the device. If two instances of `Device` have the same `Address`, then the same external measuring device will be used.

I'd like to mimic that behavior in code (for using methods like `Contains` and `Distinct`) by overriding `Equals` and implementing `IEquatable<T>`:

```
public class Device : IEquatable<Device> {
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return Equals(obj as Device);
    }
    public bool Equals(Device other) {
        if (null == other) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Address.Equals(other.Address);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm ignoring the `Tag` property in the implementation of `Equals`.

**So, my question is:** Should I ignore the `Tag` property in the implementation of `Equals`? Does doing so make the code harder to understand? Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do? I need the `Tag` property because, often, the user will not know the `Address`, or even whether or not the `Device` has an `Address` (that is taken care of in the App.config file, and the user will be dealing with an interface called `IDevice` which doesn't have an `Address` property).

**Update:**

Thanks everyone for the responses.

So, I gather that I should be using a custom `IEqualityComparer`. Do you have any guidance on how to do so if my real code looks more like this?

```
public interface IDevice {
    string Tag { get; set; }
    double TakeMeasurement();
}
internal class Device : IDevice {
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }
    public double TakeMeasurement() {
        // Take a measurement at the device's address...
    }
}
```

Should I check the device type in my `IEqualityComparer`?

```
public class DeviceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IDevice> {
    public bool Equals(IDevice x, IDevice y) {
        Contract.Requires(x != null);
        Contract.Requires(y != null);
        if ((x is Device) && (y is Device)) {
            return x.Address.Equals(y.Address);
        }
        else {
            return x.Equals(y);
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IDevice obj) {
        Contract.Requires(obj != null);
        if (obj is Device) {
            return obj.Address.GetHashCode();
        }
        else {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a followup question then you should ask it separately. This way the two different questions can both get good answers without any confusion about which part is being answered. You can of course put in a reference to the previous question for some context (and copy paste relevant bits into the new question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your current implementation is definitely confusing. The equality you've defined is clearly not the right notion of equality for devices.

So, rather than implementing `IEquatable<Device>` as you've done, I'd define an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Device>`, maybe

```
class DeviceAddressEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Device> {
    public bool Equals(Device x, Device y) {
        Contract.Requires(x != null);
        Contract.Requires(y != null);
        return x.Address.Equals(y.Address);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Device obj) {
        Contract.Requires(obj != null);
        return obj.Address.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You can pass instances of `IEqualityComparer<T>` to `Contains`, `Distinct` and other LINQ methods that depend on equality (e.g., `GroupBy`).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But, the type Device is internal to my assembly. I've updated my question with a different implementation. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 4):

First of all you forgot to override `GetHashCode()`, so your code is broken.

IMO you should override `Equals` only if two objects are equivalent for all purposes. And objects with different `Tag`s seem different for some purposes.

I wouldn't override `Equals` on these objects at all. I'd rather implement a custom comparer `IEqualityComparer<T>` and use that where appropriate. Most methods that have a notion of equality, take an `IEqualityComparer<T>` as optional parameter.

I wouldn't forbid `null` parameters, but handle them. I've also added an early-out for referential equality.

```
public class DeviceByAddressEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IDevice> {
    public bool Equals(IDevice x, IDevice y) {
        if(x==y)
          return true;
        if(x==null||y==null)
          return false;
        return x.Address.Equals(y.Address);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IDevice obj) {
        if(obj == null)
          return 0;
        else
          return obj.Address.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you want to check the type, depends on context. When overriding `Equals` I typically check with if `x.GetType()==y.GetType()`, but since you're using a special purpose comparer here, which deliberately ignores part of the object, I probably wouldn't make the type part of the identity.

Comment: I do override GetHashCode, I just left it out of the example. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Also, I updated my question. The type 'Device' is internal to my assembly. Do you have any input on implementing IEqualityComparer<IDevice>?

Comment: @ken added an `IEqualityComparer<IDevice>`

Comment: Thanks again. There is no contract for 'Address' on 'IDevice', though.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I ignore the Tag property in the implementation of Equals?

No, I think this is a bad idea.

> Does doing so make the code harder to understand?

Absolutely: a new developer would not understand how come two devices with different tags put in a hash set become one device.

> Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

There are at least two ways that I can think:

- Provide a custom comparator
- Add a class called `DeviceWithTag`, and keep the `Device` "tagless".

I would prefer the second approach, because it does look like your `Tag` models a real-world "tag" glued onto the device *locator*, which ignores its tag other than for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to implement equality in terms of `Tag` at all? It doesn't sound like you do, so I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

If the user doesn't need to know about `Address`, then you might also argue that they don't need to know about the underlying equality based on address... do they? If they don't, then again, I would say there is nothing wrong with your approach.

If they do need to know about equality, then you may need to rethink your design and expose `Address` in some way.

Comment: No, they do not need to know about the underlying equality based on address. Do you have any comments about the other answers that disagree with yours? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding `IEqualityComparer<T>`, I admit I don't know enough about .NET and they might be right. Regarding `GetHashCode`, true but you already addressed that. Regarding their opinions that two devices with different tags might become one in a `HashSet` (etc.) and that could be confusing, I think they are making assumptions that tags are supposed to be meaningfully different, which in turn relies on an assumption that all fields should be equal for equality, and I reject that assumption. I think you know best what you need. You might need to document very carefully to avoid confusion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new interface for `IDevice` to implement. The new interface also lets me easily create equality comparers based on the device.

```
public interface IPhysicallyEquatable<T>
{
    bool PhysicallyEquals(T other);
    int GetPhysicalHashCode();
}

public class PhysicalEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    where T : IPhysicallyEquatable<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (null == x) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
        if (null == y) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");
        return x.PhysicallyEquals(y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        if (null == obj) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        return obj.GetPhysicalHashCode();
    }
}

public interface IDevice : IPhysicallyEquatable<IDevice>
{
    // ...
}
```